# NavigationDrawer. Переходы между фрагментами

Tags: java, android

Насколько я понимаю при нажатии на `item`, которые находятся сбоку, мы открываем фрагмент.

Интересует следующий вопрос:как на главную активность добавить фрагмент и замещать его при нажатии на один из итемов?

Answer (score 4):

При работе со связкой `Navigation Drawer` + `Fragments` можно выделить два механизма работы приложения:

1. При выборе в `Navigation Drawer` определенного фрагмента, текущий видимый фрагмент скрывается (*hide*) и отображается (*show*) выбранный фрагмент.
2. При выборе в `Navigation Drawer` определенного фрагмента, текущий видимый фрагмент замещается (*replace*) выбранным фрагментом (**см. ниже пояснение**).

Принципиальная разница между этими двумя подходами заключается в том, что в первом случае, *скрываемый* фрагмент не изменяет свое состояние и методы его жизненного цикла (при его *скрытии* и *отображении*) не вызываются. Во втором же случае, для фрагмента, который замещается будут последовательно вызваны методы его жизненного цикла:

- `onPause()`;
- `onStop()`;
- `onDestroyView()`;
- `onDestroy()`;
- `onDetach()`.

Следовательно, в первом случае, при возвращении к *скрытому* фрагменту мы увидим его состояние на момент *скрытия*, а во втором случае фрагмент будет создан с нуля, то есть данные, которые находились на нем, мы уже не увидим.

(**пояснение**): честно говоря, навскидку не могу сказать, в какой ситуации можно, а точнее нужно применять второй подход (именно при смене фрагментов из `Navigation Drawer`)... но чисто технически это возможно (и в каких-то случаях может даже и нужна именно такая логика работы).

В подавляющем же большинстве случаев используется именно первый подход, потому как именно он наиболее логичен при использовании `Navigation Drawer` + `Fragments`: пользователь может переключаться между экранами без потери данных на них.

Пусть имеются два фрагмента: `FragmentA` и `FragmentB`, ниже я приведу два метода: первый (`changeFragment(...)`) используется для *переключения* (*скрытия*/*показа*) фрагментов без потери данных, а второй (`replaceFragment(...)`) – для *замещения* одного фрагмента другим.

```
private void changeFragment(String neededToShowFragmentTag) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    List<Fragment> existingFragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();

    Fragment currentShownFragment = null;

    if (existingFragments != null) {
        for (Fragment fragment : existingFragments) {
            if (fragment.isVisible()) {
                currentShownFragment = fragment;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (currentShownFragment == null || !currentShownFragment.getTag().equals(neededToShowFragmentTag)) {

        Fragment neededToShowFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(neededToShowFragmentTag);

        if (neededToShowFragment == null) {
            switch (neededToShowFragmentTag) {
                case "fragment_a":
                    neededToShowFragment = new FragmentA();
                    break;
                case "fragment_b":
                    neededToShowFragment = new FragmentB();
                    break;

            }
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragments_container, neededToShowFragment, neededToShowFragmentTag);
        }

        if (currentShownFragment != null) {
            fragmentTransaction.hide(currentShownFragment);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.show(neededToShowFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

---

```
private void replaceFragment(String neededToShowFragmentTag) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    Fragment neededToShowFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(neededToShowFragmentTag);

    if (neededToShowFragment == null) {
        switch (neededToShowFragmentTag) {
            case "fragment_a":
                neededToShowFragment = new FragmentA();
                break;
            case "fragment_b":
                neededToShowFragment = new FragmentB();
                break;
        }

        if (fragmentManager.getFragments() == null) {
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragments_container, neededToShowFragment, neededToShowFragmentTag);
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragments_container, neededToShowFragment, neededToShowFragmentTag);
        }

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Далее размещаю `layout`-файлы и код всех классов, дабы Вы смогли легко у себя все это собрать и посмотреть разницу.

**menu_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_main_fragment_a"
        android:title="Фрагмент А"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_main_fragment_b"
        android:title="Фрагмент В"/>

</menu>
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragments_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**fragment_a.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_a_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Фрагмент A"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fragment_a_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Do it!"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**fragment_b.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_b_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Фрагмент B"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fragment_b_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Do it!"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**FragmentA**:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    private TextView mTextView;
    private Button mButton;

    private int i = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

        mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_a_text_view);
        mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_a_button);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                i++;
                mTextView.setText("Фрагмент A : " + i);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

**FragmentB**:

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    private TextView mTextView;
    private Button mButton;

    private int i = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);

        mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_b_text_view);
        mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_b_button);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                i++;
                mTextView.setText("Фрагмент B : " + i);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String FRAGMENT_A_TAG = "fragment_a";
    private final String FRAGMENT_B_TAG = "fragment_b";

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private NavigationView mNavigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

                int itemId = item.getItemId();

                switch (itemId) {
                    case R.id.menu_main_fragment_a:
                        replaceFragment(FRAGMENT_A_TAG);
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.menu_main_fragment_b:
                        replaceFragment(FRAGMENT_B_TAG);
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void changeFragment(String neededToShowFragmentTag) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        List<Fragment> existingFragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();

        Fragment currentShownFragment = null;

        if (existingFragments != null) {
            for (Fragment fragment : existingFragments) {
                if (fragment.isVisible()) {
                    currentShownFragment = fragment;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (currentShownFragment == null || !currentShownFragment.getTag().equals(neededToShowFragmentTag)) {

            Fragment neededToShowFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(neededToShowFragmentTag);

            if (neededToShowFragment == null) {
                switch (neededToShowFragmentTag) {
                    case "fragment_a":
                        neededToShowFragment = new FragmentA();
                        break;
                    case "fragment_b":
                        neededToShowFragment = new FragmentB();
                        break;

                }
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragments_container, neededToShowFragment, neededToShowFragmentTag);
            }

            if (currentShownFragment != null) {
                fragmentTransaction.hide(currentShownFragment);
            }
            fragmentTransaction.show(neededToShowFragment).commit();
        }
    }


    private void replaceFragment(String neededToShowFragmentTag) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        Fragment neededToShowFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(neededToShowFragmentTag);

        if (neededToShowFragment == null) {
            switch (neededToShowFragmentTag) {
                case "fragment_a":
                    neededToShowFragment = new FragmentA();
                    break;
                case "fragment_b":
                    neededToShowFragment = new FragmentB();
                    break;
            }

            if (fragmentManager.getFragments() == null) {
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragments_container, neededToShowFragment, neededToShowFragmentTag);
            } else {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragments_container, neededToShowFragment, neededToShowFragmentTag);
            }

            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```